# Pull the value from the first visible row in column F after autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

How would I pull the value from the first visible row in column F after an autofilter? I want to Debug.Print the value in VisibleCount().

```
Sub GetPrimaryContacts()

Dim Col As New Collection
Dim itm
Dim i As Long
Dim CellVell As Variant

'Get last row value
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Loop between all rows to get unique values
For i = 3 To LastRow
    CellVal = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & i).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

' Create workbooks - Token Not activated
Call TokenNotActivated
For Each itm In Col
    ' If IsNull(itm) Then Debug.Print "None" Else Debug.Print itm
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=itm
    Call VisibleCount
Next

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End Sub

Sub VisibleCount()
    Dim r As Range, n As Long, itm
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("A1:A" & n).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If r.Count - 2 > 0 Then Debug.Print itm & "-" & r.Count - 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is similar to what I posted in your last question. It returns the first visible row as a `Range`. I leave it to you to select the cells within that range:

```
Function GetFirstFilterAreaRow(ws As Excel.Worksheet) As Excel.Range
Dim FilterArea As Excel.Range
Dim FirstRow As Excel.Range

With ws.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If .Areas(1).Rows.Count >= 2 Then
        Set FirstRow = .Areas(1).Rows(2)
    'if the first row is filtered out
    ElseIf .Areas.Count >= 2 Then
        Set FirstRow = .Areas(2).Rows(1)
    Else
        'No visible filtered values
        'This Else clause is only for clarity, not actually required
        Set FirstRow = Nothing
    End If
End With
Set GetFirstFilterAreaRow = FirstRow
End Function
```

It would probably be helpful to read about the the [AutoFilter.Range property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841129%28v=office.15%29.aspx).